# TKINTER doesn't work with Python&Spyder 3.7.9 August 2020

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

:o( Hello!
I've installed the new standalone (i.e. not Anaconda) Spyder64bit_full.exe (i.e. 64 bits because I have Windows 7 pro 64 bits) including the recent stable Python 3.7.9 August 2020.

A simple "from tkinter import *" script leads to this error in the IPython console:
*File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 36, in 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.*        [not foundable, in English]

When I manually add tk86t.dll and tcl86t.dll to \Spyder\pkgs I get another error: *"TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:...This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly."*

Am I supposed to do anything more with Spyder&Python to have TKINTER working properly ?!
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This sounds like a python problem, not a spyder problem. Why didn't you install anaconda? How did you install python? Did you build it from source? Try wiping python from your system and then installing a fresh copy with the official installer from python.org.

Comment: Hi Novel, I did not install Anaconda because Spyder site wrote "Spyder now offers Standalone installers for Windows and macOS, making it easier...we recommend this install method on those platforms to avoid most problems with package conflicts and other issues."

Comment: I initially installed Python 64 bits from python.org then installed Spyder, but when I got the DLL bug, I noticed that Spyder installed another Python in \Spyder\Python, so to avoid conflicts I unistalled everything (Python and Spyder), I cleaned the Registry and \Users\me\spyder folders they forgot to clean, and reinstalled Spyder only. Still doesn't work, the same error.

Comment: Would anybody please advise me because I am totaly blocked on my programs. Do you recommend to install Python in addition to the Spyder standalone install package which includes Python ?  Should I rather uninstall this strange new standalone Spyder for PC, and go for an Anaconda distribution for Spyder&Python? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We didn't consider to package Tkinter as part of our installers because we provide Qt as part of them for people's GUI needs. However, we'll try to do that in a future release.

Comment: In the meantime, please download [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a conda environment with it and connect it to Spyder. That's explained in the second part of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) of ours.

Comment: Thank you very much Carlos! Clear. So the best for me would be to rather access training based on Qt which is powerful, despite its partly open source partly commercial license is pushing me into big debates Qt vs wx vs Kivy vs Tkinter ;o)